# how to check if postgres gracefully shutdown

Tags: postgresql

I have some code that will perform a pg_rewind if it detects that the standby is out of sync. However I saw in the documentation that it requires that the database was gracefully shutdown before this command is run. I would like to be able to detect if postgres did not shut down gracefully so I can:

1. start and stop postgres ahead of time so pg_rewind will work
2. know if I should run some checks on my data to see if it is ok

I'm assuming that having it shut down non-gracefully either means it crashed, the server crashed or was told to shutdown immediately, so it would be nice to know if something bad happened and I should do something like run pg_checksums.

Answer (score 0):

[`pg_rewind`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrewind.html#id-1.9.5.9.6) and [`pg_checksums`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgchecksums.html#R1-APP-PG_CHECKSUMS-1) both require a cleanly shutdown server.

You could probably try and replicate PostgreSQL's own checks that normally lead to a *"database system was not properly shut down"* entry that appears in the server log after startup. But you can just as well simply use those - and since they require a startup, you can also let it attempt to recover and perform a fresh, clean, [graceful smart shutdown](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/server-shutdown.html). To avoid any immediate connection attempts, you could use a different port for that cycle.

For a regular server, checking [`pg_is_in_recovery();`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-RECOVERY-INFO-TABLE) after startup would be some indication of a non-graceful shutdown taking place earlier, which causes the db to enter recovery mode on the next startup. However, by design a standby always stays in recovery mode until promoted, so that won't mean the same thing here.